# How to create a secure BBCode?

Tags: xss, bbcode

Right now, people can use XSS in my URL BBCode, and I don't know how to fix it. I had attempted to fix it a while ago, but someone some how bypassed it!

```
function filterScript($content) { 
    $pattern = array('/href="javascript:[^"]+"/', '/style=":[^"]+"/');
    $default = array('#', 'color: #337ab7; text-decoration: none');

    return preg_replace($pattern, $default, $content);
}

function bbcode($input) {
    $search = array('/\[a url="(.+?)"\](.*?)\[\/a\]/is');

    $replace = array('<a href="$1" style="color: #337ab7; text-decoration: none" target="_blank">$2</a>');

    $bbcoded = preg_replace($search, $replace, $input);
    return filterScript($bbcoded);
}
```

Yes, I do use strip_tags, mysql_real_escape_string, and striplashes.

Comment: Some ways to bypass XSS filters: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet Unless you have the knowledge and ability to account for every possible evasion trick, I recommend using a well-known and trusted library.

Comment: Your code appears to allow anything at all in the `url` attribute, including quotation marks. That's leaving the proverbial barn door wide open, and is almost certainly the source of your problems. I agree with @AlexanderO'Mara in that you shouldn't try to roll your own unless you have a thorough understanding of the whats and the whys, and even then you might not want to. Cryptography isn't the only area where deferring to existing expertise can be a good thing. Rather than trying to solve this, seriously consider using an existing library and focus on the business value of your software.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling anything posted to the site is automatically has strip_tags, mysql_real_escape_string, and striplashes used on them.

Comment: *"anything posted to the site is automatically has strip_tags, mysql_real_escape_string, and striplashes used on them."* You didn't say that originally. Please don't assume that we are mind-readers; take care to include the relevant information in your question.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling the problem is that it doesn't stop these XSS attacks that are happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The specific problem** with your code is that you don't actually escape anything and allow user-defined HTML code at multiple places.

This is the code you create:

```
<a href="$1" target="_blank">$2</a>
```

The values `$1` and `$2` are user-controlled and both need to be filtered (in different ways).

- For `$1` you need to make sure that it's not possible for an attacker to escape from the attribute by supplying double quotes (`"`). One way to achieve this is using [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/de/function.htmlspecialchars.php). Another problem (which you tried to address) is that links can start with pseudo-protocols such as `javascript:`. Therefore you should also whitelist a few plausible URI schemes. A restrictive but safe method would be to limit the input to URLs starting with `http[s]://`.
- For `$2` you need to disallow any HTML tags. Again, a quick-and-dirty solution would be applying `htmlspecialchars()`. But note that this can cause problems if you plan to support nested BB tags.

**The general problem** is that regular expressions are not the right way to process nested markup, especially not for security purposes. It's very easy to [mess this up](http://blog.kotowicz.net/2010/09/bbcode-wont-protect-you-from-xss.html). Try to rely on the tools of your framework or use libraries such as [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/). You should also look at some [basic guides](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/06/preventing-xss-vulnerabilities-in-php-everything-you-need-know) on preventing XSS.