# Custom BBCode preg_replace exploit (patch help needed)

Tags: bbcode

I am having an issue where people are able to exploit my custom BBCode. I am unsure how to patch this up, and was hoping someone here would help me. In the code below, there is a lot more BBCode in the arrays, but I only have provided the vulnerable one.

```
function BBCode($input) {
    $input = htmlentities($input, ENT_QUOTES);

    $search = array('/\[font color=(.+?)\](.*?)\[\/font\]/is');

    $replace = array('<font style="color: $1">$2</font>');

    $bbcoded = preg_replace($search, $replace, $input);

    return $bbcoded;
}
```

If I were to post something like `[font color=#5fd233; font-size: 50px]test 2[/font]`, then it would include the font-size attribute too. I have tried a third party fixed called `HTMLPurifier`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Note that code review is generally off-topic on SecuritySE. You also got some hints [back then](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/143640/how-to-create-a-secure-bbcode). :)

Comment: I know that I got some help back then, but they weren't to helpful in patching it.

Comment: Hopefully somebody here has the experience to help me.